# Blackberry prob with FIELD_BOTTOM in HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, button, horizontalfieldmanager

I an trying to implement a screen like below:

[image]

For that, I am using following code. It is not working at all.

```
HorizontalFieldManager outerManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_BOTTOM|USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
        outerManager.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/bghome.png")));

final FCLabelField selectedLabel = new FCLabelField("Hello World", LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.HCENTER);

selectedLabel.setFontColor(Color.BLACK);
selectedLabel.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x00cccccc));
outerManager.add(selectedLabel);

HorizontalFieldManager innerManager = new HorizontalFieldManager();

innerManager.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);


innerManager.add(new ButtonField( "Button 1", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | ButtonField.FIELD_RIGHT ));
innerManager.add(new ButtonField( "Button 2", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | ButtonField.FIELD_RIGHT ));
innerManager.add(new ButtonField( "Button 3", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | ButtonField.FIELD_RIGHT ));
innerManager.add(tab4);
innerManager.add(tab5);

outerManager.add(innerManager);

innerManager.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x00cccccc));

add(outerManager);
```

What is the problem in my code? How I can set a screen like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you asked. One way is to use the `setStatus()` method as **BBdev** suggested (it will work only for screens of type `MainScreen` and won't work for screens of type `FullScreen`). Another alternative would be to do the alignment to bottom *manually*.

Important alignment rules to remember:

- A HorizontalFieldManager can only align fields vertically. When adding fields to horizontal manager, only these alignment styles have effect: FIELD_TOP, FIELD_VCENTER, FIELD_BOTTOM.
- A VerticalFieldManager can only align fields horizontally. When adding fields to vertical field manager, only these alignment styles have effect: FIELD_LEFT, FIELD_HCENTER, FIELD_RIGHT.

Here is a code snippet that does what you asked.

```
public class UISandbox extends MainScreen {
    public UISandbox() {
        super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH);

        HorizontalFieldManager outerManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
        outerManager.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/bghome.png")));

        VerticalFieldManager innerMngr = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_BOTTOM); 
        final LabelField selectedLabel = new LabelField("Hello World", FIELD_HCENTER) {
            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        selectedLabel.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x00cccccc));
        innerMngr.add(selectedLabel);

        GridFieldManager innerInnerMngr = new GridFieldManager(1, 3, USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        innerInnerMngr.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        innerInnerMngr.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
        innerInnerMngr.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
        innerInnerMngr.setColumnProperty(2, GridFieldManager.AUTO_SIZE, 0);
        innerInnerMngr.add(new ButtonField("Button 1", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | FIELD_HCENTER));
        innerInnerMngr.add(new ButtonField("Button 2", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | FIELD_HCENTER));
        innerInnerMngr.add(new ButtonField("Button 3", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK | FIELD_HCENTER));

        innerMngr.add(innerInnerMngr);
        outerManager.add(innerMngr);
        add(outerManager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add all the buttons in one `HorizontalFieldManager`, and use setStatus(the hfmInwhich you have added the buttons). This will set the button at the bottom of the screen. And Add the labelField `Hello world` before setStatus. Thats it. :)

Comment: How to set the background image?

Comment: `setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource(your image path)))`; try to call this on manager.

Comment: and you want to set the background so just make a hfm give it the required height and use the above code on that manager and add that before your setStatus();

Comment: Are you telling me to set the hfm to FIELD_BOTTOM|USE_ALL_HEIGHT and add another hrm in it, all the buttons will be added in the inner hrm?